# Issue with count labels in ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, label

I've just finished a beginners course on R and was playing around with some datasets to practice. I wanted to add count labels to my chart below:

```
ggplot(data=inpatient_data, aes(y=count)) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x=condition,y=count,fill=condition)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())+
```

[Frequency of medical conditions amongst rehabilitation patients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcWrN.png)

I followed tips to use geom_text(), and this is the resultant code:

```
ggplot(data=inpatient_data, aes(y=count)) + 
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x=condition,y=count,fill=condition)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=after_stat(count), vjust=-1))
```

[Frequency of medical conditions amongst rehabilitation patients with count labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3V6e.png)

But the result becomes really whack and I'm not sure how to even figure out what's wrong. Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is right when when you want to add labels to a `geom_bar`. In your case `geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=-1))`should be sufficient as the "count" or the variable to be mapped on `y` is already a column of your data.

Comment: I've only recently gotten into ggplot but if your y is already a count don't you want your stat to be "identity"?